# iimPlay is not defined

Tags: javascript, imacros

Can anyone help me to solve the following error

"iimPlay is not defined"

The above error occurs when i run the following script

`iimPlay('c:\Users\COMPAQ\Downloads\Amym.iim');`

I dont know about `imacros`

Comment: As it says, iimPlay has not been defined. You're missing or incorrectly importing whichever script is supposed to create it.

Comment: You need to define the function in some script before being able to call the function.  Where did you get this "information" from?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just simply paste the script into `Macros` folder inside `My Documents\iMacros\` and use this.

```
iimPlay('Amym.iim')
```

Comment: I already said that I am facing iimPlay is not defined, I want to know that should i import any library for that

Comment: No, just check is the file .iim or .js .
The file from which you are playing iimPlay command.